# Automatically refresh fields

Tags: ng-admin

Is there a way in ng-admin to refresh values (content of the fields) without refreshing the entire page?

For example, if there was a REST API that returns a value that changes over time (e.g. amount of requests in a queue). How could I create an ng-admin page and let the "queue length" field update every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-admin` doesn't have such a feature.
You have to write your own page by overwriting the router.
See [Adding Custom Pages](https://ng-admin-book.marmelab.com/doc/Custom-pages.html) on the documentation.